# eval_objective command for automatic architectures

Tags: openmdao

This is an automatic architecture code(source: http://openmdao.org/releases/0.13.0/docs/tutorials/mdao/optproblem.html)
I have a doubt that what will be the code to print the minimum value of the objective function. 
It may be very trivial but I am not getting it. I tried using eval_objective but it is not working. What code is to be added to this existing one?

```
def display_results():
    print "Minimum found at (%f, %f, %f)" % (problem.dis1.z1,
                                    problem.dis1.z2,
                                    problem.dis1.x1)
    print "Couping vars: %f, %f" % (problem.dis1.y1, problem.dis2.y2)
    print "Function calls dis1: %d, dis2: %d"%(problem.dis1.exec_count,problem.dis2.exec_count)
    print "\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that code assumes that the optimizer finished and left the model sitting at the point that gave the lowest objective. For all gradient based optimizers this is a reasonable assumption.

To do the same thing in openmdao > 1.7.x, see the following tutorial: 
http://openmdao.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.3/usr-guide/tutorials/paraboloid-tutorial.html#optimization-of-the-paraboloid-with-a-constraint

```
print('Minimum of %f found at (%f, %f)' % (top['p.f_xy'], top['p.x'], top['p.y']))
```

Comment: I agree with you that gradient based optimizer may give us a local optima but my question is how do I get print that optima value. There has to be some command to print it.